# moment-timezone format doesn't return the expected result

Tags: timezone, momentjs, utc, datetime-conversion

Using the `tz()` function from [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) as follow:

```
moment.tz('2017-10-15 13:53:43','Asia/Hong_Kong').format()
//returns '2017-10-15T13:53:43+08:00'

moment.tz('2017-10-15 13:53:43','Asia/Hong_Kong').format('h:m A')
//I expect to return '9:53 PM' but it returns '1:53 PM'
```

Ultimately, I want to apply the `fromNow()` function to format the result. But when I apply it, it uses the initial timestamp and ignore the timezone applied.

```
moment.tz('2017-10-15 13:53:43','Asia/Hong_Kong').fromNow()
//I expect to return '1 min ago' when actual time is 13:54 UTC (21:54 in HK) but it returns '8 hours ago'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is wrong with this question? Googled this topic for a couple hours and the above seems the right approach. Yet I don’t get the expected result. If anyone can guide me towards the right direction or explain in case of downvote would be more helpful.

Comment: `moment.tz('2017-10-15 13:53:43','Asia/Hong_Kong')` creates a date/time that corresponds to **1:53 PM in Hong Kong**. The `format` method just prints this same value, so it's unclear why you expect 9:53 PM as output.

Comment: Could you also [edit] the question and add the code that uses `fromNow()`, with examples of inputs and expected vs actual outputs? It's not clear to me what *"uses the initial timestamp and ignore the timezone applied"* means.

Comment: Added the explanation for fromNow(). About the format, I expect to apply + 8 hours since when I apply the tz() function to the date time string, the format() function return +08:00 at the end of the date time string. What you are saying is that the tz() function is just used to define the timezone of a given date time provided? What I want to achieve is to take the UTC date and time from my database and convert it into the timezone of my user. So '2017-10-15 13:53:43' in UTC becomes '2017-10-15 21:53:43' in Hong Kong or '2017-10-15 21:53:43' in UTC becomes '2017-10-16 05:53:43' in Hong Kong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
moment.tz('2017-10-15 13:53:43','Asia/Hong_Kong');
```

You're creating a date/time that corresponds to **October 15<sup>th</sup> 2017, at 1:53 PM in Hong Kong** - which, in turn, corresponds to `2017-10-15T05:53:43Z` (**5:53 AM in UTC**).

When you call the `format()` function:

```
moment.tz('2017-10-15 13:53:43','Asia/Hong_Kong').format();
```

It returns:

> 2017-10-15T13:53:43+08:00

The `+08:00` part is just the [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) - it just tells that [Hong Kong is 8 hours ahead UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/hong-kong/hong-kong?year=2017). But `2017-10-15T13:53:43+08:00` (**1:53 PM in Hong Kong**) is exactly the same instant as `2017-10-15T05:53:43Z` (**5:53 AM in UTC**). That's why `fromNow()`, when the current time is **13:54 UTC**, returns 8 hours.

If you want the date/time that corresponds to **1:53 PM in UTC**, you should use the `utc()` function:

```
// October 15th 2017, 1:53 PM in UTC
moment.utc('2017-10-15 13:53:43');
```

Now, when the current time is **13:54 UTC**, `fromNow()` will return 1 minute (because the date/time represents **1:53 PM in UTC**).

To convert this to Hong Kong timezone, just use the `tz()` function:

```
// convert 1:53 PM UTC to Hong Kong timezone (9:53 PM)
moment.utc('2017-10-15 13:53:43').tz('Asia/Hong_Kong').format('h:m A');
```

This will convert **1:53 PM UTC** to Hong Kong timezone (resulting in **9:53 PM**):

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation!